# Random Access in Spark RDD?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I am wondering if Spark RDD supports random access. If there any way to control the order of partition such as `RDD[0], RDD[1], ..., RDD[n-1], etc`.

Comment: Just asking why do you need this, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: We need to loop the RDD in particular order (dependent).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define the Order of the Partitions but you can always define the way your data should be partitioned.

for example - Consider using "partitionBy" function defined for PairRDD's. 
By Default Spark uses "HashPartitioner" but we can use "RangePartitioner" and provide the ranges.

We can also define our custom partitioners.